# Simplifying typescript types inside type popup

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to simplify the type that is being shown in the type-tooltip that is visible when I hover over a variable in Typescript?

I have the following code:

```
type Debug<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key]
}

type Chainable<Acc = {}> = {
    option: <K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) => Chainable<Acc & {[k in K]: V}>;
    get: () => Debug<Acc>;
}

declare const config: Chainable
const result = config
  .option('foo', 123)
  .option('name', 'type-challenges')
  .option('bar', { value: 'Hello World' })
  .get()


type X = typeof result;
```

When I hover over `result` variable I get:
[[image: hovering over result variable 1]

However, when I hover over `type X` I see:
[image: hovering over a typeof result]

**Questions:**

1. Why are those types shown differently? (Even though they represent the same thing)
2. Is there a way to show the type like it's shown in the second screen?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBGBXA5gHgCoD4oF4oG8AoKEqAbQGsIQoBLAOyipAHsAzKdAXQC5PLqXQgF9CoSFADCACwCGDWfAA2EVAEEAxhtwFh2PEVJQWYYLRb0%20qANJQIAD2AR6AEwDOUN8ABODZABooADVMAApmPmtAgDdZJUQIPiCASlxsGXl6RRV1LSgAMgJKOkZrXmC9AG5iUmQIYD5Q1JxsOCQ0TQ1MatFCFwgNJVlvaA0LLygx%20jZaZD4MhWUIQimJkbdEJWAdKZnkGoA6EzMLUIByNhYWM8CARgAmAGZkw%20PzenOsgFsIG6gz8QQAC0GjkShU9DqbjOLxIR1M73O8GGf3wUFi8US-wAEhBwSwoAB1FjeJQuM5QYSwqAHOrAJqEMTgaAADR0gPYUHWm2A1UIQA)

Answer (score 6):

It seems it is possible to create a utility type that will do the flattening automatically. So, there is no need to dissect the type the way @zecuria did.

```
type Chainable<Acc = {}> = {
    option: <K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) => Chainable<Acc & {[k in K]: V}>;
    get: () => Util_FlatType<Acc>;
}

type Util_FlatType<T> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: Util_FlatType<T[K]> } : T
```

[image]

Util_FlatType is stolen from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhlAwgJQPIBl3QCqpwCQFFoAhVbXAWQEIpZo64BeF1t9jzr7lxhmONgAWASwDO0AO4iANjOgAjAKbQArgDsAtgEMR6gC6712hTKUAaaGID20fUKUAnFdudXrmlY9VmJASWh1JSUAEztbADNrOWtJADo%20PgBVfVkAfTh9AE8AByUJVxV1a30rPIBjEQiRcvDoAEF4bDFLBVVSwugAcyUgxxqceDVUmRFU-ISBaAA5DLtc-OhO4pCVCO1y-Wt%20icSpwgA3JyzoAAVXMSU4JQAPCv0JMcf1HPbAkrry6wMjJfUTszaEJ6LpSUT6fI5Da7KZ8c6OS6ZBYSJRjByOaDOfSqRzqJZnC5KQiORzbAA8lHyYm0PQAfNBtvjsTkzNAANrTayrSzTW76eDWHHlJQAXUmsGAUCg2TyBIRTmJpMcJG0l2gTGgAG9oE4lQAuOzeFQAXwA3NKFnLLo5FeTKWJqT0dTcIeoQhIxPp%20uoupYBUKVHzeu6rF6QerQ96uvSNfbHSoAGTQFLpABiMm0%20mwCzJ8OttuVqsTWvcAYN-scwugxtp5sgMpUBbSSXUzg2QhMrI1eYVJPJACJ6g6nKlvgaW23yh3TCoG-3axbZU2W7d7qEAOK9Jw1eBhn0Rns2vuOMn9ld3JSbULdLf9WqeqPzPLzusN6BNwgXq8hMkAdQ7pRBm6Hp7r60D-k4gYusGIFRn6gqVlBrohg%20IIxlavZKmSAAGn5rmEADkAAkmr-pmxoEUsEQQhixGkeiSgUdh8EBgukCLioKYyGk6aZtmeRktg6HYM6yESNYCgAFaXqUAD8JZsgA0tAejQAA1koWTWBEOAiuOIw8RmWY5tgSkivSxrQAa2AcdAAAaEZcYZfE5pq2h6gAjJZSaagoBoAEw1lK7H1pajTYJyqyCZaQEoaBlinKSORiOhTm8cZAnag21mWt5ZxJSlr6WrM0yqJ4d7oGMTjaDIZIAGo1aoSEwZGaERuFkVKKepXlTUlU0TV-aWNqByNUoBoNTITXVmxb6zCQeiuFkeHOA6IjfGSqA5KJLWoT6ljoEo1GWMgIhdEI%20joR1XJdf2C3GI4y13KtYjreoQ0ltYeSONoboGltlhmNRBqHcdmJnRdBqnedpQ1nWtmEJm-5VWIULCmIZIVlWsWwW1TB0K1%2044wgCFVvJh4Fqe574TefQDHtoJzvSeoE1jzXAdA2HQCRegRE4Mx8saXPyYj%20jIxCqPQhjvIuszrOk0o8OhbKiDfKk6hNWSyD5D4%20g8nyO0cwz6FstrYi65Yovi5CUtkjLl0ikrb49j1yiOGkeg0cYtXwqkNWG3FcEkwGAe4z6MYEwzofB4h0Ai8ezZBF%20EIhJudPlLuj4szAMfY9BHPYQADDz6h8xi9tC3HGGu04HsGE43s4SRvsiDVxqF8xAuy1Z8sh8T2EeSXZdd-olfk4SNfu57Dc1U3mot23Hmd-bcs52z0fYf5Q-8xXwvV2Vbt117s-Yc3rh%20zIxr%20cvfKr9AufsyG2EAMzb%20Xgt7y7B%2019PuIn2fjgL7Gmfjfbu2d77r37gAFjfiPMe%209NCH1-o3U%2089z6t0vlA0Bl0e5rwVhvAArLA3eVcv6IJ-vXP%20tVUEL0vgQ7Bd8H4bwAGzEI-qQie38p6UJQQAoBzCGG4Igfg-uAB2NhLp4FkKQTw-%20aDAEYONKIwR4CmH9wABwSNHp-Th5DuHH2oXwxR6iVG91jv3AAnFoqRuiZEGLnrQ40FjTE5zZLQliiFHbBWdrYpwmMRH50DnjSOoFo7r3jkqROq4ZIblvDuUJqjpEUPsf2D6bN6TEzZKkjxwoRQcPlEeLC-Y-DqFGqMMIGs9FpIVowpJ%20iZ61WyQ-DJgSJBslQbzHeXChaWA6aXHeH88nyQ5GkHq25yj9WqrVSetJLZI3BDbdGdtb55NUcuVsSh2ydkVt4y0PZEoiB0I9FaVI3ppChM4AwDhXoAC9Qj%20L7q0wm0Z1QhMfMTcJ74E7UxianOJGcEkE32f0I5T0cgvTORc3o9h8giDuSENIXwDB6E1j2eoIRgSpCOCctaG10lsVssCw5S0cWvW%20OcwoVzYXwsRWrFFXUza62jmyCS0lNiWAZnkgAPhhQp2wVSXAjjnRlMhAJPJZVJGSHLQJDIJvfKOxMRX6DZB5IZXzIk-O-GncZmdwyqPvkqlVeT%204AEprF71NjrUVbJC4ijmWLBZkslkr1WXK9V2w0h4V%20aeE1H1%20zwmhdcuFoRSVvQ%20oa1VjClVOz2YSA5oLQ14oCWJZ5Qr5WhI%20fgiJHrNUp21XeXV%205VGQKedhAAFOa-Jlx40kueqc8lUKqW3PuVbR1aN8jLNlrU3xJ50m7NlD2SgusRAshqJmEQ2K624vUA88xTzjavJzgqp5nz1nRK1f8wtoJElxpBbW8F9aZ3pOZZ0jEoM9acxALA2hu9ZU53voO4do7yjjsnQe6dZJW0o3bRjG9t8WkprZKe6A0MLq9PNXe%20%20UH2TzUWscqdZKZ39hAB9c9J0IaXXtdbJ1HaXVCKgx%20ZO9z%20yJvepYZDH0-1gKBbu4l8H32IdncKADLUgP9LPUdC92FgDXvQTVW9cc3WPtFSO0YL6sVEgQ29T98zv22yo5dFjHM2PD1A1xiDgn71QZGfdfdEKNr9mAKhzj6GYazPfLJiWP7O0O3w-fQj%20FTykb9UZhKfGZAr3w0ShNUmk2sRPex6AaHOYAFJeMKP44MzT0HhOpGfa%20yTDHpNfqs-J9zK8lMhhU-zNT4HNTAYE7JN198dNwbBfppDIXjNgzU%20ZlLizcMrLs%20692XrvxOd82R6A-YqtuYix52%20XnaM%20aS35xCBLlYqDRRisYE7EsVaY4-MOLz8ZLozSurNLWolEb%20enLdQ35RDpE-FiTpHFuZbacB4L2EADU4WL6FaE4SdFmK5tnfqzh396X-0BdUxhvLBWotFa0yV2DD1yuHtPDd6rF7atYbbbbPD%20qtttZTh10bXX%20zQ76w9wbO7DtPrEwls7x7MlXZM5zAAtPdjBj2tPTde2%20hbH3rMKdpBd9kwHcucw08D6DoO0i6fowt-slOYemYunVyzDXpZNeRw571JHOt%20rFzj2neOaME%20O0T07nXztK0JYSROkgfo5CVVrK1YrAOsqlc87lvKCwCqUGmkDlvmU2-ZXb6LUHl0pojWqtdO383xKzm6lntt-cc9SVXQ1trmsU2PFTJONMtgaS65H-D0b%201TcJIt6OC7VvpveRtkO2b3a5tiXtwFOcezG9N%20bhns2meQ-D0s-FE23zhQPLn-sUDoDAGgH3m70APL0HUS%20Wyan2pNCyf0GG-YvGQCAA)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```js
type Chainable<Acc = {}> = {
    option: <K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) => Chainable<{[k in K | keyof Acc]: k extends keyof Acc ? Acc[k] : V}>;
    get: () => Debug<Acc>;
}
```

Basically this is doing the same thing as what you're doing but in a more round about way.

Instead of relying on `&` parameter which will pollute the hover hint. You can effectively recreate the entire object from scratch.

This is achieved by using `k in K | keyof Acc` as the key but it also means you need a conditional type for the value.

I imagine this maybe less performant but honestly i don't think it will make the most difference.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQeYnw)

Answer (score 1):

This is a primary difference between the `type` keyword and the `interface` keyword.  Interface names appear in tooltips but type names do not.